# Variable length bitfield

Tags: c, bit-fields

tl;dr: How can I properly generate a variable length bitfield in C?

I have a structure containing a variable number of elements for instance:

```c
struct s{
    int v1;
    int v2;
    /* ... */
    int vn;
}
```

I'd like to create an anonymous bitfield of the size of the struct. Since i want low coupling between my two structs I do like this:

```c
struct x{
        unsigned long a:sz(struct s);
};
```

This code works but leads to issues:

1. What can I do if the struct has a size above 64 bits?

   - I can use several ints to store my bitfield but that gets messy and overkill.
   - I could also use a pointer to a void* but I suspect performance loss
2. By design my bitfield will generate AND for each operation over it deteriorate performances as seen in the following code

```
int main() {
 560:   41 54                   push   %r12
}

__fortify_function int
printf (const char *__restrict __fmt, ...)
{
  return __printf_chk (__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
 562:   4c 8d 25 cb 01 00 00    lea    0x1cb(%rip),%r12        # 734 <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
 569:   55                      push   %rbp
 56a:   bd 64 00 00 00          mov    $0x64,%ebp
 56f:   53                      push   %rbx
 570:   bb 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%ebx
 575:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
                struct x x = { .a = 3, };
                for(int i=0;i <100; ++i){
                        ++x.a;
                        printf("%u\n", x.a);
 578:   0f b6 d3                movzbl %bl,%edx
 57b:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 57d:   83 c3 01                add    $0x1,%ebx
 580:   4c 89 e6                mov    %r12,%rsi
 583:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 588:   83 e3 0f                and    $0xf,%ebx
 58b:   e8 b0 ff ff ff          callq  540 <__printf_chk@plt>
                for(int i=0;i <100; ++i){
 590:   83 ed 01                sub    $0x1,%ebp
 593:   75 e3                   jne    578 <main+0x18>
                }
                return 0;
}
 595:   5b                      pop    %rbx
 596:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 598:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 599:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
 59b:   c3                      retq   
 59c:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

Ideally I'd like to do something similar to the following pseudo-code (but this is obviously invalid in C).

```c
#define varint(sz) (sz > 32) ? \
                        ((sz>64) ? "#error size too huge" : int64_t) : \
                        ((sz>16) ?  int32_t: int16_t)
varint(sizeof(s)/sizeof(int)) mybitfield = 0;
```

How can I properly generate a variable length bitfield in C?

Comment: tl;dr: can't...

Comment: use bitwise operators to extract the field yourself

Comment: @phuclv The problem is not to extract the field which is straightforward but to create the right size "blob" for my struct

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I guess you are right, it must not be possible to do it in a clean way. I still think that it is possible to do it using a variable length array  `uint8_t bitfield[sz/8]`, and wrapping read like that `#define read_field(f,n) (f[n/8] & (1<<(n%8)))`, no?

Comment: @MaximeB. yes, basically.

Comment: Perhaps a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It remains dirt but I think this is the best way to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: not sure what is the context of your problem, but in my experience sometimes the best solution with big header files filled with complex structs that have size and format dependencies is to auto-generate them using some script.